# Apache FilesMatch (global config) priority over local .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I want to protect all Wordpress admin interfaces (wp-login.php/wp-admin) in my server. To do this, I want to create a global config in Apache, asking for a fixed user/password (HTTP basic authentication), before reach the real WordPress login page. This will avoid overload PHP from password scan bots.

```
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
 AuthUserFile /etc/wordpress.passwd
 AuthName "TYPE USER wp AND PASSWORD wp"
 AuthType Basic
 require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

Works, any file named wp-login.php will ask for the password.

But when I run in a Wordpress site, its **.htaccess** has some kind of "priority" over the global config. When I access wp-login.php I just receive a 404 error. If I remove/rename .htaccess, FilesMatch works, but I lost the "path mask" feature, that is necessary.

Wordpress .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I'm looking for a way to FilesMatch directive has priority over the .htaccess (Rewrite module): ask for the password, not rewrite the URL (giving 404).

Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly in the "global config" have you put these directives? The "404 error" you are seeing - is this a WordPress generated 404 or Apache?

Comment: The global config is after the last VirtualHost entry. And the 404 error is from Wordpress. Note: the global config position does not seems to affect. I tried.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Wordpress .htaccess rewrites everything, including the ErrorDocument directives, that are used by HTTP Basic Authentication, 401 and 403 return codes. I had personalized SHTML files for ErrorDocument (default in cPanel servers). So, instead of ask for a password, it rewrites the HTTP headers, asking for the password *and* showing a 404 error page at same time, letting the web browser crazy.

To fix, I just forced the default ErrorDocument messages:

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
```